# How to read site's web.config file from Azure WebJob?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-webjobs

I am using custom web.config configuration elements to configure complex application services for my ASP.NET MVC application. I need this configuration data in my Azure WebJob which is deployed alongside the web app. I am trying to avoid copying these sections from website's web.config to webjob's app.config file.

So, apart from connection strings and application settings, is there a way for an Azure WebJob to read the website's web.config file?

Ideally, I would like to use ConfigurationManager.GetSection to create my custom ConfigurationSection instances.

Comment: Can't see exact manual for doing this. It looks like it should be done while building on dev machine or while deploying to an instance. On dev machine it can be in msbuild script or similar. In an instance it can be done during start up task (see this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh180155.aspx). Hope it helps!

Comment: @Artem The msbuild script sounds interesting... If I understood corectly, you suggest creating a script which will copy these sections from one project to the other on build event? Could you please elaborate more on this? What about the XSLT transforms that are already used to transform web.config file based on the current build configuration? How are these going to be affected?

Answer (score 2):

Most web apps + web jobs have sensitive settings that you ***don’t*** want in a config file. You can deploy those secrets using ARM/PS see [deploying secrets to Azure](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/best-practices-for-deploying-passwords-and-other-sensitive-data-to-aspnet-and-azure). So just add all your settings to your ARM/PS script.

Azure App settings apply to the web job and the web app, this is the recommended approach.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to documentation on MSDN or azure.com for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for a build time. Probably this sample Msbuild script would insert a peeked xml elements from your web.config into another xml file. Please note it is not tested.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PublishPackages > 
        <WebConfigXml>
            $(YourProjectPath)web.config
        </WebConfigXml>
        <WebJobConfig>
            $(YourWebJobPath)app.config
        </WebJobConfig>
    </PublishPackages>
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="InjectConfigs">
    <XmlPeek 
        XmlInputPath="%(PublishPackages.WebConfigXml)" 
        Query="//parent/someelement">
        <Output TaskParameter="Result" ItemName="Peeked" />
    </XmlPeek>
    <XmlPoke 
        XmlInputPath="%(PublishPackages.WebJobConfig)"
        Query="//parent/someelement"
        Value="$(Peeked)"
        Condition =" '$(Peeked)'!=''" 
        />
</Target>
</Project>
```

These docs can help: [Configuring Parameters for Web Package Deployment](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/configuring-parameters-for-web-package-deployment), [XmlPeek task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff598684.aspx)
And if XmlPoke and XmlPeek won't do the thing another way is to use [XmlFile task](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/3.5.14.0/index.html). Hope it helps!

UPDATE. Changed to use only XmlPeek and XmlPook without XmlFile.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for installation time. There is a technology called Web Deploy that allows to create packages which can be run from command line and install services. And it allows parameterization of .config files by using one xml file called Parameters.xml. This one can be shared by your web site and Web Job I believe. The [howto manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398068.aspx) on doing it.

Answer (score 0):

One approach we used for a similar purpose to this was to put all the common configurations on a Table Storage account in Azure and built a helper class that reads the configuration from what we referred to as: "Run Time Configuration", which is basically a configuration database that is hosted in Azure Table storage and all components could read that information...

Comment: Surely you can use any shared data store for that purpose, but I am specifically interested in .config files because they have a number of practical advantages for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `CloudConfigurationManager` class in the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager` NuGet package.

ie. 
`var val = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(key);`

I find that this seems to pull the settings from the host Web App while running on Azure. If you're debugging locally you'll still need to set the App.config values, I'm afraid.

Edit: Just re-read your question again (d'uh!) and saw your comment about using Sections. AFAIK that's not supported by this class - AppSettings section only unfortunately.